# Axis2 web services not generated [?wsdl]

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, wsdl, apache-axis

I am experiencing a problem querying wsdl for Axis2 web service.

We have list of web services published through Axis2 on Tomcat web server. 
When i query using URL,

http://HostName:/xyz/services/myservice?wsdl

it throws "Internal Server error" and found following error in Tomcat log.

---

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [AxisServlet] in context with path [/xyz] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.getEPRsForService(AxisServlet.java:579)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.calculateEPRs(AxisService.java:981)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.calculateEPRs(AxisService.java:931)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getEPRs(AxisService.java:924)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.setPortAddress(AxisService.java:1386)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printDefinitionObject(AxisService.java:1009)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printUserWSDL(AxisService.java:1030)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1306)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:270)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I learnt that on `?wsdl` as a part of URL, Axis generates WSDL file dynamically. but I couldn't find which component/configuration/library is responsible not working correctly and how this problem can be fixed.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What version of Axis2 are you using?

Comment: Appreciate some response.

Comment: We are using Axis2 1.5.1. Now, I have turned on axi2 debug log and when i query for WSDL using http://HostName:/xyz/services/myservice?wsdl, i can see, the log message "DEBUG org.apache.axis2.wsdl.util.WSDLWrapperBasicImpl  - WSDLWrapperBasicImpl.getServices()" without any error.

Comment: It's definately a strange error. Looking at the source code in grepcode.com for 1.5.1 version it seems there's no AxisServlet.java already, they dropped it in 1.4 but I guess grepcode.com is not accurate. In cases like this, since the error gives no information I would just put a breakpoint on AxisServlet class, line 579, check which is the object that is null, and if needed just go steps before until this null object is retrieved. Use an eclipse decompiler plugin if you need to (https://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/)

Comment: You can take a look at the source code here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/axis2/transport/http/AxisServlet.java.html 

It has something to do with the Axis ConfigurationContext but I think you will have to debug this class anyway.